# Restructuring column names in a df

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a data with column names that look like this:

```
 X121.10.21    X131.90.23
```

I want to remove the `X` at the beginning of each string, remove the third number after the `.` and then reorder the first and second number. Like this:

```
 10.121    90.131
```

How can I do this? I would especially appreciate a way to do this with `dplyr`, if possible.

Comment: How did you get that dataframe? If it is read.table, then use `check.names=FALSE`.

Comment: @akrun added another one, should be OK, plus there is now your answer below.

Comment: @akrun you can dupe tag it, too. No need to assume stuff.

Comment: @zx8754 Also, none of the dupes really get the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub`, capture as a group and replace with the backreference of the captured group

```
names(df1) <- sub("X(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\..*", "\\2.\\1", names(df1))
```